# Can't find width element for p in my CSS

Tags: html, css, width, tumblr

I'd like a little help understanding what I'm doing wrong in CSS.

Here is my page:
http://lejournalucl.tumblr.com/post/74788681108/uni-ski-trips-on-evite-ou-on-ose

I see the width of the p element here is 800px, and I'd like to change it but I can't find it in the code. Can you tell me why please?

Comment: no, your `p` is not 800px

Comment: have you tried your browsers dev tools?

Comment: The `p` seems to have a fluid width, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Is your monitor 1024px wide (800/80%)? Try on a desktop monitor or a screenshot service

Answer (score 3):

Your `p` elements are just filling the available space—the normal behavior. The space is determined by the width here:

```
.permalink article {
    width: 80%;
}
```